# How to implement a "visual" tutorial in iOS

Tags: ios, touch

first of all, sorry for the non-relevant title but I don't know how to exactly define it.

I would like to implement a tutorial like the one illustrated in the picture here below

[image]

how can I do that in iOS? Is there any framework, library, example or standard procedure to implement such tutorial? Or is it just a picture added on top of the main view?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just an `UIImageView` on top of the view. Do you want some other functionality for which a simply `UIImageView` won't suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at some of [these controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tutorial). You should be able to get a good idea of how to approach this. Essentially, you are going to want to create a partially transparent Image and overlay that on the relevant view when you wish the tutorial to display. Create a tappable "hit zone" that covers the entire area of the image, so that a user can dismiss the overlay with a single tap.

Good Luck with your project!